# Raspberry Pi stuck at black booting screen

Tags: boot, screen

Right now I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3rd Generation, and a LANDZO 3.5 Inch Touch Screen with a CanaKit 5V 2.5A Raspberry Pi 3 Power Supply  It's been working until yesterday when I tried to boot it up. At first, I thought that it needed some time so I waited a few (5) hours and the screen didn't change. Is the problem with the charger or what?

[image: Boot Screen Error]

CanaKit 5V 2.5A Raspberry Pi 3 Power Supply ([https://www.amazon.com/CanaKit-Raspberry-Supply-Adapter-Charger/dp/B00MARDJZ4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480910878&sr=8-1&keywords=raspberry+pi+3+charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MARDJZ4)).

Comment: Welcome to the site. There isn't enough information in your question to prompt a decent diagnosis of the problem, and your screenshot is indecipherable. As it stands the most likely candidate is probably the power supply - have you measured it during use to establish that it's putting out the required 5V?

Comment: It used to work, so I'm assuming it does put out a 5V.